# problem representing a register with unions and bit fields

Tags: c++, struct, cpu-registers, unions, bit-fields

I'm writing a NES emulator in C++, and I bumped into an issue using bit fields to represent a register, which caused a very nasty bug. I'm representing an internal address register as:

```
union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint16_t coarseX : 5;            // bit field type is uint16_t, same as reg type
            uint16_t coarseY : 5;
            uint16_t baseNametableAddressX : 1;
            uint16_t baseNametableAddressY : 1;
            uint16_t fineY : 3;
            uint16_t unused : 1;
        } bits;
        uint16_t reg;
    } addressT, addressV;   // temporary VRAM adddress register and VRAM address register
```

so I can access the single bit-fields, and the register as a whole.

Initially I wrote the register as:

```
union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint8_t coarseX : 5;             // bit field type is uint8_t, reg type is uint16_t
            uint8_t coarseY : 5;
            uint8_t baseNametableAddressX : 1;
            uint8_t baseNametableAddressY : 1;
            uint8_t fineY : 3;
            uint8_t unused : 1;
        } bits;
        uint16_t reg;
    } addressT, addressV;   // temporary VRAM adddress register and VRAM address register
```

The bug was caused by the bit field behaviour when the type of the bit field (for example coarseX) is different from that of the register (reg). 
In this case, when I increment a field (i.e. coarseX++), the reg member was updated "incorrectly", meaning that the bit pattern inside reg didn't reflect the pattern represented by the bit fields (or by the bit fields as I layed out them inside the struct).
I know that the compiler can pack bit fields inside "allocation units", and may even insert padding, but why the behaviour changes when I change the type of the bit field?

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: So, for future, I advise not to use bitfields, instead write accessors and use bitshifts and bitmasks. Bit-fields padding depends on implementation. What compiler, compiler version and compiler options are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said it yourself:

> I know that the compiler can pack bit fields inside "allocation units", **and may even insert padding**, ...

That is exactly what is happening.

`uint8_t` has 8 bits in it.  The 1st two fields in your struct, `coarseX` and `coarseY`, having 5 bits each, can't fit consecutively within a single byte in memory.  The compiler stores `coarseX` in the 1st byte, and then has to push `coarseY` to a 2nd byte in memory, leaving 3 unused bits in memory between `coarseX` and `coarseY` that offset your values in the register.

The next 3 fields, `coarseY`, `baseNametableAddressX` and `baseNametableAddressY`, total 7 bits, so they fit within that 2nd byte.

But that byte can't hold the `fineY` and `unused` fields, so they get pushed to a 3rd byte in memory, leaving 1 unused bit in memory between `baseNametableAddressY` and `fineY` that offset your values in the register. And the register can't access that 3rd byte!

So, effectively, your `struct` ends up acting as if you had declared it like this instead:

```cpp
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            // byte 1
            uint8_t coarseX : 5;
            uint8_t padding1 : 3;

            // byte 2
            uint8_t coarseY : 5;
            uint8_t baseNametableAddressX : 1;
            uint8_t baseNametableAddressY : 1;
            uint8_t padding2 : 1;

            // byte 3!
            uint8_t fineY : 3;
            uint8_t unused : 1;
            uint8_t padding3 : 4;
        } bits;
        struct {
            uint16_t reg; // <-- 2 bytes!
            uint8_t padding4; // <-- ! 
        }
    } addressT, addressV;   // temporary
```

Using `uint16_t` instead of `uint8_t`, you don't run into that problem with extra paying being added, since there are enough bits allocated for the register to hold all of the bits you are defining.

Comment: so to recap, if I use uint8_t the allocation unit is a byte, and since the implementation doesn't allow straddling between bytes it inserts padding. If I use uint16_t the allocation unit is 16-bit wide (unsigned short maybe), and since the bitfields don't cross the byte boundary they're paked togheter. This is what Visual C++ does (in my case), but it could change from another implementation. Am I right?
What if I use different data types for each bit field?

Comment: @Luca yes, whenever you straddle across the boundary between allocation units, whatever size they are, you are going to get padding inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The type you use for bit fields is what gets used for storage internally. And the actual layout is fully implementation-defined. I suppose your compiler packs bit-fields into storage units (uint8_t in the “bad” example), but doesn’t let them span storage unit boundary. Like:

```
    uint8_t coarseX : 5;
// 3 bits remain (out of 8), not enough for coarseY. So these become padding,
// and next storage unit starts here
    uint8_t coarseY : 5;
    uint8_t baseNametableAddressX : 1;
    uint8_t baseNametableAddressY : 1;
// 1 bit remain. Again, too little.
    uint8_t fineY : 3;
    uint8_t unused : 1;
```

In the “good” example, 16 bits was enough for all the bit-fields so the compiler could pack them in the way you need. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field for more information.

Also remember that accessing inactive union member is UB in C++. So it’s probably better to use a single uint16_t field and accessors (which don’t prevent the type being POD/trivial/standard-layout).